# Shortening a link using HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the design of the navigation on my site.

We have some products with really long names and I want to cut them short and maybe add (...) or something similar at the end.

So something like this should look like `abcdefg...` instead of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

```css
a{
  width:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a>
```

A JS solution is welcome.

I would also like to know why the width isn't being applied?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp also anchor by default displays inline so add display: block / inline-block if you want overflow property to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors are inline elements by default and any width set on an anchor is ignored. Change the display to inline-block:

```css
a {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a>
```

As MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements):

> Inline elements are those which only occupy the space bounded by the
>   tags defining the element, instead of breaking the flow of the
>   content.

and...

> You can change the visual presentation of an element using the CSS
>   display property. For example, by changing the value of display from
>   "inline" to "block", you can tell the browser to render the inline
>   element in a block box rather than an inline box, and vice versa.
>   Hovewer, doing this will not change the category and the content model
>   of the element. For example, even if the display of the span element
>   is changed to "block", it still would not allow to nest a div element
>   inside it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `white-space` combined with `overflow` & `text-overflow`. And don't forget to add `display: inline-block` to the `a` element, so you can apply `width` to it.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a>
```

Comment: had tried this with no success. it was the inline-block that was throwing me off

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Yep, I will include that to the answer.